# cordapp-template-java "Cannot resolve symbol 'docs'"

Tags: java, corda

I have been working my way through the [Hello, World! Tutorial](https://docs.corda.net/hello-world-flow.html) from V2.0 and cannot import the following variable.

```
import static net.corda.docs.java.tutorial.helloworld.TemplateContract.TEMPLATE_CONTRACT_ID;
```

Intellij informs me that it "Cannot resolve symbol 'docs'".

Is this a known issue or have I incorrectly setup the [cordapp-template-java](https://github.com/corda/cordapp-template-java) project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved this issue by using:

```
import static com.template.TemplateContract.TEMPLATE_CONTRACT_ID;
```

The definition for this variable can be found [here](https://github.com/corda/cordapp-template-java/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=TEMPLATE_CONTRACT_ID&type=).