# Hello, World! Pt.2 - Contract constraints - Writing the contract - Defining IOUContract: Java code discrepancy

Tags: java, corda

While writing out the IOUContract Java code and comparing the V2.0 to the Master docs, I noticed that the Master copy of the docs does not include the following import statements:

```
import net.corda.core.contracts.Contract;
import net.corda.core.transactions.LedgerTransaction;
```

This appears to be an error as the IOUContract implements the Contract interface, and the IOUContract.verify function takes a LedgerTransaction object as an argument.

Could someone clarify whether the omission of these import statements is correct?

Also, will any corrections applied to the master branch be merged into the release-V2 branch? Or is it the intention that newcomers to Corda should follow the Master version of the tutorials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The imports are *additional* imports. The Java Template the tutorial is based on should already have `Contract` and `LedgerTransaction` imported.

But if you don't have them, yes - go ahead and import them.

In general, any change to the `master` docs will be backported to the docs of the latest stable release (`V2` currently), if applicable (e.g. if the changes to the `master` docs don't correspond to the documentation of some new API existing only on `master`).

Comment: Thank you for replying. I saw [this](https://github.com/corda/corda/pull/2234) PR relating to previous problems discovered in the V2.0 tutorial documentation, but, as far as I can tell, these commits were only applied to the Master docs. There has been no change to V2.0 documentation.

Are the respective docs built from the master and release-V2 branches? Or is there some other system in place for creating the documenation/ tutorials?

Comment: AFAIK the changes were made to the V2 docs. Take a look at https://github.com/corda/corda/commits/release-V2. The changes are cherry-picked in instead of PRed - maybe that's why you're not seeing them?

Comment: I'm still seeing an error under [this](https://docs.corda.net/releases/release-V2.0/hello-world-flow.html#flowlogic) section as I have described [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47730995/cordapp-template-java-cannot-resolve-symbol-docs).

Users/ Devs following the tutorial will encounter a compilation error using the code example provided.

Comment: Hmm - this is a little confusing. So the docs.corda.net docs get updated in line with master, but the docs.corda.net/releases/release-V2 ones don't. The idea is that the V2 docs are a snapshot in time, while the main docs (docs.corda.net/) correspond to the latest docs for the current stable branch. Hope that makes sense!

Comment: This makes sense! Thank you for explaining.

Comment: It is worth noting that when using the drop down to change versions of the docs, selecting V2.0 links to https://docs.corda.net/releases/release-V2.0/ and Master links to https://docs.corda.net/head/. These are both different URLs to https://docs.corda.net/, which, when navigated too, displays V2.0 in the drop down (on my machine).